# Why is the city-state influence I gain from gifts of gold decreasing in Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5

Recently the influence points I get from a city state when I gift gold is decreasing.
Why does this happen?

The other AI is having a guarded attitude towards me because they covet my land - how can I make them friendly?  I did attack some of them.

Comment: You should post the second part as a separate question.

Comment: "Continually decreasing" as in, each gift provides less influence, or "Has Decreased" as in, gifting gold used to give 50 influence, now it gives 30?

Comment: If you boost the right cultural settings, then you can improve the amount of influence per gift, and lower the rate at which influence decreases - this can offset the game mechanic of reducing gift influence over time.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I believe that the amount of gold decreases over time, not based on how much you give. I think this is because gold is a lot scarcer and harder to acquire in the early game then it is in late-game. (Think about it, 300 gold treasuries aren't easy to get in early game, I've had 1000+ gold without much trouble at all later on.)

Regarding befriending the AI, it's basically a matter of being nice to them. Simply sign all sorts of deals with them (open borders, resource trades, research agreements), and give them stuff, and they'll start to like you more. Also, try to agree with any of their requests when possible (pacts of cooperation/secrecy, alliances, demands, etc.), and that should help you out as well. Although, since you attacked them, it will probably be an uphill battle to win their friendship. (I know I wouldn't befriend any player that tried to conquer me! XD)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine if someone gave *you* money all the time.  It would be great at first, but eventually you'd get used to it and come to expect it.  It wouldn't be special anymore, and your opinion of that person couldn't just keep increasing forever.  This idea is programmed into the game!

Comment: so should i attack that city-state to regain it respect?

Comment: I don't think that would work.  You can help them against their enemies and that sort of thing to gain influence, as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, and is a game balancing issue. The amount of gold you can gift is always fixed (to 250, 500 or 1000), but the amount of influence you receive will decrease over the course of the game.

This is because (for most players anyway) the amount of available gold will *increase* over the course of the game, so this is basically inflation in the cost of influence.